# Div will not move up to where it should

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside a div that will not move up into the center where I want it to. It is the image called youthcouncil

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="file:///E:/Crios%20Óige/Crios%20Oige%20Images/Logo.png" id="logo">
    <img src="file:///E:/Crios%20Óige/Crios%20Oige%20Images/Title.PNG" id="title">
    <img src="http://www.youtharts.ie/sites/youtharts.ie/files/NYCI%20Logo%20Full%20JPG_2.jpg" id="youthcouncil">
</div>
```

Corresponding CSS

```
#header {
height: 100px;
width: 2000px;
background-color: #993333;
margin-top: -10px;
}
#youthcouncil {
height: 80px;
width: 180px;
margin-left: 300px;
margin-top: 5px;
}
#logo {
height: 80px;
width: 180px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 5px;
}
#title {
height: 80px;
width: 180px;
margin-left: 250px;
margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: `margin-left: 300px;` Somethings really wrong

Comment: please share a preview or a fiddle so that we can see the problem

Comment: So you want the image youthcouncil centered vertically in the div with the red background correct?

Comment: Here's a demo guys, http://jsbin.com/dedumote/1/edit

Comment: can please explain what you actually trying to achieve, I can't tell you any solution without knowing what you want.

Comment: I wanted the image labelled youthcouncil to be in the exact center of the div. In a vertical shape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED

I removed some parts for you, to make it easier to see how it works. Now you should be able to add back your other images etc.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UKAEu/2/

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="http://www.youtharts.ie/sites/youtharts.ie/files/NYCI%20Logo%20Full%20JPG_2.jpg" id="youthcouncil" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #993333;
}
#youthcouncil {
    height: 80px;
    width: 180px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: relative;          /* make it moveable */
    left: 50%;                   /* push left edge to center */
    margin-left: -90px;          /* push back half its width */
}
```